# Multiple Javascript files, I want to take out URL constants into a seperate file

Tags: javascript

As the title says, I have a few javascript files. There are sections that call a few websites. I want to be able to store the websites in a different file, this way if the website changes we just need to make one change and not many.

Any suggestions?

I tried doing something like

```
/**
 * Returns URLs
 */
var URLCONTEXT = "/root-url/context/";
var URLROOT = "/root-url/";

function getContextUrl(){
    return URLCONTEXT;
}

function getRootUrl(){
    return URLROOT;
}
```

but this doesn't have a way to communicate with the other JS files =/

Comment: How do you include those files?

Comment: Once all the JS files are loaded, they're all able to see each other.

Comment: Is this the entire file, or is it inside a class or function? If you declare the URLCONTEXT and URLROOT variables in the global context, they are available to all other scripts.

Comment: In my index.jsp and other jsp pages, I was just doing a <script src="js/foo.js"></script> for each one. Yes, this is the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your url constants in a js file like

```
url-constants.js

var URLCONTEXT = "/root-url/context/";
var URLROOT = "/root-url/";
```

and reference this js file first before other js files.

and you will be able to use url-constants variable in any other js file.

```
other.js

function getContextUrl(){
    return URLCONTEXT;
}

function getRootUrl(){
    return URLROOT;
}
```

include these in your page like

```
<script language="text/javascript" src="url-constants.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript" src="other.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yup, this worked. I guess I didn't have it high enough. It didn't work until I put it above the jquery.js scripts...

Answer (score 0):

var's defined outside of a function, and functions defined with a name are in the global namespace. You can access them from your other JS files as long as this JS file is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that. Just make sure the file with the urls is included *before* the files where it's accessed from.

Also, I would not recommend polluting the global scope with these, even if you named them in capital letters. How about defining

```
var URLS = {
    urlContext: '/root-url/context',
    urlRoot: '/root-url'
};
```

and using them in other files with URLS.urlContext and URLS.urlRoot?